# GNU grep and composite patterns

Tags: regex, parsing, grep, pattern-matching

I have read [why GNU grep is fast](https://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-current/2010-August/019310.html) and also the implementation of [Boyer-Moore](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm) but what I really want to know is how grep works with composite patterns such as `pat1|pat2` or even `[ABC]`.

Is grep building a parse tree? Or the composite pattern is checked as if it was a list of simple patterns?

So far I have not found any reasonable site which explains it.

A quick explanation along with a reference will be appreciated.

Comment: Here's the reference: http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git/tree/ without a quick explanation, though ;)

Comment: What do you mean by "parse tree"?

Comment: @rici I meant something like the trie that is built for Aho-Corasick algorithm. I know it's not a 'dead-on' definition but I lack a better word..

Comment: @VaultDweller: That's a trie :), which is a type of tree, to be sure, but has little or nothing to do with parsing. If you meant "Is grep constructing a finite automaton?", the answer is yes, as per my answer and the linked essay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other than reading the code, as suggested in a comment, the best place to start is [Russ Cox's interesting and readable essay](https://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html) on regular expression matching. Russ describes the algorithm for constructing a DFA (Deterministic Finite Automaton), mentioning that `grep` and `awk` both use variants of this algorithm.

The Gnu versions of those utilities construct a [non-deterministic finite automaton (NFA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_finite_automaton) using something like [Thompson's NFA construction algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thompson%27s_construction), and then construct the corresponding [deterministic finite automaton (DFA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton) lazily, as Russ suggests, to avoid potential exponential blow-up in the NFA->DFA algorithm. Lazy execution of the [powerset construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powerset_construction) algorithm does not require any change to that algorithm; it simply does the needed computation on demand, keeping a cache of computed powersets. If the cache size exceeds some limit, cache entries are deleted to make room for the new ones.

GNU grep also includes a number of optimizations designed to make it work faster in practice with common patterns, and those optimizations complicate the code considerably. However, if you want to start reading the source, you could start with the functions in Gnulib for NFA->DFA conversion algorithm  in [dfa.c](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gnulib.git/tree/lib/dfa.c) (function `dfaexec_main`, which both moves through the DFA and computes new states on demand), and for the NFA construction in the file [regcomp.c](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gnulib.git/tree/lib/regcomp.c) (function `re_compile_internal`).

---

Since it was mentioned in a comment, I should clarify that that what OP calls "composite patterns" are really just patterns which use the alternation operator <kbd>|</kbd> in one of its guises (including the optional operator <kbd>?</kbd>, which could be written as `(...|)`. and character classes, which are just a compact representation of alternation, as Russ points out in the linked essay.)

There is another possible meaning to "composite pattern", since grep allows the specification of multiple patterns, either by using the `-e` command-line argument more than once, or by using the `-f` option to read patterns from a file, one per line. Grep then performs a simultaneous search on all the patterns, which you could think of as a composite search. However, that is really no different from simple alternation; internally, grep just joins all the options together into a single long regular expression punctuated with the alternation operator before compiling it into a single NFA.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that alternative patterns (OP called them 'composite patterns') are each a pathway through the state machine.  Grouping these pathways and incrementally progressing through the groups simultaneously is the trick to simulating NFA in DFA. Something I didn't recognize until reading this paper (thanks!) was that character-classes are really just a "concise representation of an alternation." Duh.

Comment: @gregory: Short of rewriting Russ's paper, I don't feel like I could do justice to a description of DFAs, NFAs and the powerset construction. That material is also featured in every parsing/formal languages/compiler construction textbook I know of, and in innumerable lecture notes scattered around the internets. I'm not at all convinced that I'm capable of doing it better than all of those people. I refer people to Russ's essay because I think he does a great job. Maybe someday I'll give it a try...

Comment: .... also note that repetition operators represent a loop in the state machine, so if there is one then you have an infinite number of pathways. The subset construction (or powerset construction as wikipedia calls it these days) does not generate an infinite state machine, and that's an important aspect of the algorithm.

Comment: @rici Thanks for an enlightening explanation! I knew about the creation of DFA but the conversion to NFA was my missing link. Thanks again!